# How to set default login domain for a Windows 2003 server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain

When users want to log into one of our servers, the default domain is set to the machine name instead of the organization's domain, which is to say that the domain dropdown shows the machine name in the text part, while the organizational domain does appear in the dropdown (populated by the network, I assume).

I have heard that one may set a default domain to appear instead of the machine name, and I need this to be that way.  I expect it's a registry entry, but I have given up finding one which applies.

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The registry location in question is `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DefaultDomainName`.

A vbscript to set this might look something like this.

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DefaultDomainName", "EXAMPLE"
```